# Python - Looking to obtain full list of permutations of Boolean values

Tags: python, list, boolean, permutation

I have the following list of variables that take on a Boolean value:

```
outcome_value=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
outcome_type=[True,False]
```

I'm looking for all possible permutations of True and False but want to specify conditions such as:

outcome_type of A must not equal outcome_type of B, same for C and D, E and F

if A=True, then C,E must equal False (in addition to condition 1 for B being met also)

if C=True, A,E=False (in addition to condition 1 for D being met also)

if E=True, A,C=False (in addition to condition 1 for F being met also)

Therefore final outcome would be like follows:

```
[(True, False, False, True ,False ,True), (False, True, False, False, False ,True), (False, True, False, True, True, False)]
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear (at least to me) what the first condition means. You say `outcome_type of A must not equal outcome_type of B` but your final tuple in the desired outcome has `(False, False, True, True...)` which looks like the A == B to me.

Comment: yea that was a typo, thanks for spotting. should be False True False...

Answer (score 1):

Is this sample input?  You've only got 6 variables, and 2^6 = 64.  Just look at all 64 possibilities and discard the ones that don't fit your criteria.

```
[(A, B, C, D, E, F) 
    for A, B, C, D, E, F in itertools.product((True, False), repeat=6)
    if A != B and C != D and E != F
    # Your last three rules are that at most one of A, C, and E are true
    if A + C + E <= 1]
```

Comment: [**Explicit is better then implicit**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2), so I'd recommend to use regular loop instead of this monstrous list comp.